# Disable buttons based on spinner choice

Tags: android, button, spinner, hidden

So I have **buttons** (not the soft key pad) on the screen but I want some to be **disabled** (can't click) when you pick a certain **spinner option**. Like I have the buttons 0-9 (for numeric input) and if "Base 2" (spinner selection 0) is picked I want all the buttons except 0 and 1 to be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a OnItemClickListener and react to the option that is given like for example this way

```
spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {           
        @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, 
                View view, int position, long id) {

                if(position == 1) 
                    button.setClickable(false);
            }

    });
```

Comment: I thought that `setOnItemClickListener` isn't supported by `Spinner`?

Comment: Oh yhea thats right, it needs to be `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()`

Answer (score 1):

`Spinner` does not support `setOnItemClickListener`.  If you try and use it, you will get an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner
```

As such, you should use `setOnItemSelectedListener`:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "position= "+position+" / id= "+id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            switch(position) {
            case 0:
                button0.setClickable(true);
                button1.setClickable(false);
                break;
            case 1:
                button0.setClickable(false);
                button1.setClickable(true);
                break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }});
```

Comment: So I mixed both of yours, I used his "if" statement but I cant make an "else if" statement for multiple spinner choices. I couldn't get your "Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "position= "+position+" / id= "+id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
" to work though

Comment: @Brendan Winter what part of it doesn't work?  You should change `MyActivity` to the class name of the activity that contains the code.